# String Replace in a URL

Tags: javascript

I need to replace the URL in the DIV with ID "___gcse_1". I created a new function, replace_url (), but adding the domain in full does not work, as there are syntax problems. my code below:

```
async function sostituisco_url() {

  var str = document.getElementById("___gcse_1").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(/www.sitoweb.it//gi, "nuova_url");

  document.getElementById("___gcse_1").innerHTML = res;
}

window.onload = sostituisco_url;
```

Comment: That seems like a bad way of doing it... You're destroying the entire DOM and rebuilding it, all to change... what, a link's URL? You'd be better off selecting the link and changing its `.href`

Comment: You might need to escape the last `/` in your regex, such as `/www.sitoweb.it\//gi`. But above advice is a far better idea

Answer (score 1):

escape / in regular expression:

```
/www.sitoweb.it\//gi
```

Comment: Why? AFAIK forward slashes have no special meaning in regular expressions, except in Perl, where they may delimit the regex. But this isn't a Perl question.

Comment: in javascript they have no meaning in The Regular Expression but it is a **key charecter** and its indicates **start point** and **end point** of a regular expr in a string.
you noticed that in the example above after indication the end of regular expression with "/" i use "g" for global and "i" for in-case-sensitive those are not as part of The regular Expression.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying. Maybe [edit] this into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
str.replace(/www.sitoweb.it//gi, "nuova_url");